# Woocommerce variations via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I hope you can help
I have a product in woocommerce that has a variation of colour. There is various form steps for the user to run through before they are give the limited version of colours as not all possible combinations support all colour combinations.

The problem comes when I've generated a select list (from ajax) with the various limited options. Once you click on the select, the list reverts back to the full list again.

There is various event listeners against the form (check_variations update_variation_values found_variation) and one of them is recreating the list. Everything else needs to run apart from updating the select list.

Any help on this would be great.
Thanks
Mark